# What is a method to calculate precisely $P(Y \geq X, Y\leq Z)$, given three independent random variables $X, Y$, and $Z$

Tags: probability

For three independent normally distributed continuous random variables X, Y, and Z (each with its own mean and standard deviation), I need a way to calculate

$P(Y \geq X, Y \leq Z)$

I know that I can do this by the following:

$P(Y \geq X, Y \leq Z) = P(Y \geq X) \cdot P(Y \leq Z | Y \geq X)$

I am able to calculate $P(Y \geq X)$ using the following relation:
$P(Y \geq X) = P(Y - X \geq 0)$

However, I'm having trouble calculating precisely $P(Y \leq Z | Y \geq X)$

Comment: Hint: Conditioned on $Y = y$, the event $\{Y \geq X, Y \leq Z\}$ has conditional probability $$P\{Y \geq X, Y \leq Z \mid Y = y\} = P\{X \leq y, Z \geq y \mid Y = y\} = \Phi((y-\mu_X)/\sigma_x)(1 - \Phi((y-\mu_z)/\sigma_Z)).$$  Multiply by the density of $Y$ and integrate.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Darn it. I have an answer I'm proud of, but I'm not sure if I ought to post it.

Comment: Just to check - are you calculating $P(x \leq y \leq z)$ or do you already know that $x \leq z$ and are calculating the probability that $y$ is inbetween?

Comment: Cyan, no it's not homework, it's just a problem that was driving me mad.

Comment: Hi jbowman. x is not necessarily <= z, so it would be P(x <= y <= z). Thanks.

Comment: Macro's hint is definitely true. I have checked this by dividing the Y distribution into 1/(2^11) parts from -6 standard deviations to +6 standard deviations. At each point of demarcation I calculated p = P{X <=y, Z >=y | Y = y} * (density at y). To calculate the area for each chunk, I did (y2 - y1) * ((p2 + p1) / 2). The answer is just the sum of the chunk areas. This seems to be a slow way though, so I will study Cyan's answer this coming week to see if I can get a way to do it without iteration.

Comment: @Abey, If you're using R or MATLAB w/ Statistics Toolbox, I can give you the code right now...

Comment: Cyan, if you could post the code in R, that would be great. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Abey, sorry for the delay -- I clean forgot about making the offer! Here it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One relatively easy approach is to consider $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as having a joint [multivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).

$\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\Y\\Z\end{array}\right]\sim\mathrm{MVN}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}\mu_{X}\\\mu_{Y}\\\mu_{Z}\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\sigma_{X}^{2} & 0 & 0\\0 & \sigma_{Y}^{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & \sigma_{Z}^{2}\end{array}\right]\right)$

Let

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
X-Y\\
Z-Y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
X\\
Y\\
Z\end{array}\right]$

Then by standard results on [affine transformations of multivariate normal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation),

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V\end{array}\right]\sim\mathrm{MVN}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
\mu_{X}-\mu_{Y}\\
\mu_{Z}-\mu_{Y}\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{X}^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{2} & \sigma_{Y}^{2}\\
\sigma_{Y}^{2} & \sigma_{Z}^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{2}\end{array}\right]\right)$

And since $P(Y \geq X, Y \leq Z) = P(U \leq 0, V \geq 0)$, you want the probability mass of this bivariate distribution in the second quadrant. This is not analytically solvable in general, but is easy to compute. If $\mu_X = \mu_Y = \mu_Z$, then there is an analytical expression ([from equation 73 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html)):

$P(U \leq 0, V \geq 0) = \frac{1}{2} \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sigma^2_{Y}}{\sqrt{(\sigma^2_{X} + \sigma^2_{Y}) (\sigma^2_{Z} + \sigma^2_{Y})}}\right)$.

**Added**: Here's R code to compute the probability.

```
install.packages("mvtnorm")
library(mvtnorm)
mu_x <- -1.4
mu_y <- 2
mu_z <- 1.7
mu_vec <- c(mu_x- mu_y, mu_z - mu_y) 
var_x <- 9
var_y <- 9
var_z <- 16
Sigma <- var_y + matrix(c(var_x, 0, 0 , var_z), nrow = 2)
pmvnorm(lower = c(-Inf, 0), upper = c(0, Inf), mean = mu_vec, sigma = Sigma)
```

Comment: Thank you Cyan. Although I'm not experienced on the level you post about, I will study upon it. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: What pieces are you missing? Maybe I can point you to some resources.

Comment: Honestly, I am not very familiar with the standardized ways of expressing these concepts. Thus, the meaning of those first three parts is unclear to me. I understand the last line; however, the means of the three distributions are not necessarily the same.

Comment: [The bivariate normal distribution](http://www.aiaccess.net/English/Glossaries/GlosMod/e_gm_binormal_distri.htm#ani_binormal) might be a good starting point -- the linked page has nice animations. Then you'll need to know about [vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) (especially [in Cartesian space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#In_Cartesian_space)) and [matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)). (cont'd)

Comment: After that you'll be ready to tackle [random vectors](http://www.aiaccess.net/English/Glossaries/GlosMod/e_gm_random_vector.htm) and the [multivariate normal distribution](http://www.aiaccess.net/English/Glossaries/GlosMod/e_gm_multinormal_distri.htm).

Comment: Cyan, are there some typos in your final displayed equation? The denominator of the argument of the arccos is of the form $\sqrt{a\cdot a}$. Also, $\sigma_Z^2$ does not appear anywhere in the formula which is a bit surprising.

Comment: Cyan, I have run the R code, and it works great. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I might just make many draws from the distribution and calculate the rate that the event you are interested in occurs. In R:

```
N=10^7
 x=rnorm(N,mu_x,sig_x)
 y=rnorm(N,mu_y,sig_y)
 z=rnorm(N,mu_z,sig_z)
 sum(x<y & y >z )/N
```

It is just an estimation so maybe do it a couple times. Quick and dirty

Comment: The final line of code should be "sum(x<y & y<z )/N".

Comment: This is a great way to check an answer.  But did you notice the word "precisely" in the question?

Comment: Thanks Seth, and ditto on good idea to check the answer.

Comment: I noticed the word 'precisely', I just ignored it. Just kidding. Both cyan's and this method can be computed with any level of precision.

Comment: Up to a point Seth: the precision is inherently limited by your computing capabilities and lifetime of the universe.  Remember, the SD of a simulated estimate scales only as $N^{-1/2}$.  That will make it prohibitively difficult to attain more than about six significant figures; your example only gets about four sig figs.  (Every once in a while even six sig figs is not good enough as a check, so this is not entirely nit-picking.)